# How to use Graph toolkit people picker with existing access token in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I have already finished login and get the access token in JavaScript file with msal-browser.min.js,  is that possible that I use this token for  ?

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AAD Test</title>

    <script src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.12.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // access token is here after page load.
        let accessToken="";
    </script>
    <div>
        <span id="username"></span>
        <button type="button" id="Sign Out" onclick="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
    </div>

    <script src="./authConfig.js"></script>
    <script src="./authRedirect.js"></script>
    <script src="./graph.js"></script>
    <script src="./common.js"></script>
    
    <mgt-people-picker></mgt-people-picker>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SimpleProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/custom#simpleprovider) with your access token.

Comment: I tried the SimpleProvider, but it didnt work for me. Only thing worked was the Msal2Provider.